# How to add Looped URLRequest image and add them to 1 viewport?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to loop (add images from Loader thru URLRequest), And the images are added to contentHolder, and then i place all these images which are inside contentHolder into a viewport. But at the moment I have to put the add images to viewport step inside the loop, so it creates a problem, which is each loop, a viewport is added. So 10 viewport overlaps each other. I tested it in debug mode and when the first image is loaded i can quickly slide it, because the viewport has a scrollpane, then second image is added, and i can slide that one, and third one is added on top etc.

But if i put the add Holder to viewport step outside the loop, it gives me the error Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null, i dont know what to do. Please help, thanks for your time! I had been trying this for 6 hrs already!

And the error is on the line viewport.addChild(_contentHolder1); which is the last part of the code, if you scroll to the bottom.

```
for (var j:int = 5; j < somedata.length; j++) 
            {

                if(somedata[j]){
                var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                var image:Bitmap;
                var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[j]);
                myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
                myLoader.load(url);




                function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
                image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);
                var currentY:int = 10;
                var h = image.height;
                var k=image.width/image.height;



                 _contentHolder = new Sprite();
                _contentHolder.y = currentY;
                currentY += _contentHolder.height + 10;
                addChild(_contentHolder);
               _contentHolder.addChild(image);







        for (var j:int = 5; j <somedata.length; j++)
             {
                 _contentHolder1 = new Sprite();


    addChild(_contentHolder1);
                 _contentHolder1.addChild(_contentHolder);


            var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();

                viewport.y = 0;

                viewport.addChild(_contentHolder1);


            var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();
            scroller.width = 300;
            scroller.height = 265;
            scroller.x = 10;
    scroller.y = 100;
            scroller.viewport = viewport;
            addChild(scroller);
        }   
        }}
```

Edit:

```
 var loadedArray:Array = new Array();
                    var counter:int=0;

                    function loadImage():void{
                    for (var j:int = 5; j < somedata.length; j++) 
                       {
                    if(somedata[j]){
                     var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                        var image:Bitmap;
                    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  onImageLoaded);
                        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[j][counter]));



                        }
    }
    }






                        function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {




                         loadedArray.push(e.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap);

           if(counter == somedata.length-1){    
        var _contentHolder: Sprite = new Sprite;
           addChild(_contentHolder);
               for(var i:uint = 5; i < loadedArray.length; i++){



                    _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i]);
                        currentY += _contentHolder.height + 10;

               }    
           }

           else{
               counter++;
               loadImage();
    }
 var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();

                viewport.y = 0;

                viewport.addChild(_contentHolder);


            var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();
            scroller.width = 300;
            scroller.height = 265;
            scroller.x = 10;
            scroller.y = 100;
            scroller.viewport = viewport;
            addChild(scroller);
}
```

Comment: Can i add an event listener to it to fix the problem?? Anyone want to help? If i have an event listener that when addChild is completed, then i add the contentHolder to viewport?

Comment: Your code is a great mess and I cannot even understand what you are trying to do. Try using tabulations. Talking about addChild - it's synchronous operations, which means that it completes immediately.

Comment: I am new to coding, not very sure what is neat or messy, sorry about that. I am just trying to use URLRequest to load images in a loop, then add them to a viewport.

Comment: If the addChild completes immediately,i am wondering why would it still say parameter child must be non null if i added child, but just the child was added in a loop, and i tried to add the child to viewport outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Starling Framework and a loader loop such as:

```
private var count:uint = 0; //add this in your class
private var imagesVector:Vector.<Image> = new Vector.<Image>(); //add this in your class
private var imagesUrlVector:Vector.<String> = new <String>["url1","url2","url3","etc"]; //add this in your class

private function loadImages():void 
    {
        //create the loader
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        //when texture is loaded
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, onComplete );

        //load the texture
        loader.load( new URLRequest (imagesUrlVector[count]));
    }

    private function onComplete ( e : Event ):void
    {
        // grab the loaded bitmap
        var loadedBitmap:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap;
        // create a texture from the loaded bitmap
        var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap ( loadedBitmap );

        var card:CustomImage = new CustomImage(texture);

        imagesVector.push(card);
        trace("load image number" + count);
        count++;
        if (count < imagesUrlVector.length) {
            loadImages();
        } else displayImages();

    }

    private function displayImages():void {
        var x:uint = 150;
        var i:Number;
        for (i = 0; i < cardVector.length; i++ ) 
        {
            x += 100;
            imagesVector[i].x = x;
            addChild(imagesVector[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am just wondering, if what i would like to perform is possible without framework?

Comment: Would this perform the same result? http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?797090-Parameter-listener-must-be-non-null

Comment: try should rely on this (doesn't use a framework): http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/seqload/

Comment: if my answer helped you, please choose my answer

Comment: Hi Roran, i am still working on it haha sorry, i am still stuck on the problem,i had been trying for more than 6 hours today, still cant resolve it.  I will choose your answer once i have resolve the problem. I just posted above on the code that i had been working on, it doesnt have error now, but it doesnt display the images.

Comment: 1 problem i have is the url is loaded from an Array which starts at 5, it is called somedata, so it starts at somedata[5].And after 1 day, i am still working on it, still can not resolve the problem, i can't add the counter onto the URLRequest, because half of the request is an Array. I found this link, i believe this is what i should follow? http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3slideshow/3.php